# Is it possible to open a menu based on the component state? Without the MenuTrigger in react-native-popup-menu

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-popup-menu

How can I open the Menu without the

`<MenuTrigger text='Select action' />`

```
// your entry point
import { MenuProvider } from 'react-native-popup-menu';

export const App = () => (
  <MenuProvider>
    <YourApp />
  </MenuProvider>
);

// somewhere in your app
import {
  Menu,
  MenuOptions,
  MenuOption,
  MenuTrigger,
} from 'react-native-popup-menu';

export const YourComponent = () => (
  <View>
    <Text>Hello world!</Text>
    <Menu>
      <MenuTrigger text='Select action' />
      <MenuOptions>
        <MenuOption onSelect={() => alert(`Save`)} text='Save' />
        <MenuOption onSelect={() => alert(`Delete`)} >
          <Text style={{color: 'red'}}>Delete</Text>
        </MenuOption>
        <MenuOption onSelect={() => alert(`Not called`)} disabled={true} text='Disabled' />
      </MenuOptions>
    </Menu>
  </View>
);
```

The [doc](https://github.com/instea/react-native-popup-menu/blob/HEAD/doc/api.md#menutrigger) saying that, **Menu can by opened by clicking on  or by calling context methods.**

I want to know how to use the **context methods** in this functional component.

Answer (score 1):

Just found a wonderful solution [here](https://github.com/instea/react-native-popup-menu/blob/HEAD/doc/examples.md#declarative-menu)

This is the sample code that [react-native-popup-menu](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-popup-menu) provided.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';
import Menu, {
  MenuProvider,
  MenuOptions,
  MenuOption,
  MenuTrigger,
} from 'react-native-popup-menu';

export default class ControlledExample extends Component {

  constructor(props, ctx) {
    super(props, ctx);
    this.state = { opened: true };
  }

  onOptionSelect(value) {
    alert(`Selected number: ${value}`);
    this.setState({ opened: false });
  }

  onTriggerPress() {
    this.setState({ opened: true });
  }

  onBackdropPress() {
    this.setState({ opened: false });
  }

  render() {
    const { opened } = this.state;
    console.log('ControlledExample - opened', opened)
    return (
      <MenuProvider
        style={{flexDirection: 'column', padding: 30}}>
        <Text>Hello world!</Text>
        <Menu
          opened={opened}
          onBackdropPress={() => this.onBackdropPress()}
          onSelect={value => this.onOptionSelect(value)}>
          <MenuTrigger
            onPress={() => this.onTriggerPress()}
            text='Select option'/>
          <MenuOptions>
            <MenuOption value={1} text='One' />
            <MenuOption value={2}>
              <Text style={{color: 'red'}}>Two</Text>
            </MenuOption>
            <MenuOption value={3} disabled={true} text='Three' />
          </MenuOptions>
        </Menu>
      </MenuProvider>
    );
  }

}
```

Hope this will help others.